# find the condition that minimum of metrics is a metric

Tags: real-analysis

suppose $X$ is a set and $e$, $f$ are two metric on the set $X$. Then I knew that $$(x,y)\rightarrow \min\{e(x,y),f(x,y)\}$$ is not a metric on $X$. There are counterexamples in which triangle inequality fails.
But I want to know under what condition this will be a metric on $X$.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Note that the two other axioms hold automatically, so it's just a matter of determining the condition under which $\min\{e, f\}$ satisfies the triangle inequality when $e, f$ are metrics.